# CloudKit and iOS7 target

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Anyone know if you can link with CloudKit - but still target iOS7 (albeit with the cloud kit stuff disabled?) It just crashes on me in the simulator - so I'm guessing not - but I can't find a definitive statement.

Thanks

Comment: You need to make the cloud kit framework optional. Read the "SDK Compatibility Guide for iOS".

Comment: @maddy thanks for the pointer. I weak linked the CloudKit framework and it worked - sort of! It worked when targeting an iPad2 on iOS7 but not an iPad Air on iOS7 (crashed!) This makes me think there is some 32/64bit shenanigans ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weak linking is the answer - but beware, it can crash in the simulator. Spoken to Apple DTS and this a known issue with the Simulator - should be ok on a real device.